# Python find specific line within <div> by <style>

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to crawl an internet page via Python's beautifulsoup. 
This is a part of the page's source code:

```
<div style="display: flex">
    <div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;width: 33%;"> apple </div>
    <div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;text-align: center;width: 28%;"> peach </div>
    <div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;text-align: right;width: 33%;" title="nofruit"> cucumber </div>
</div>
```

So what I'm trying to get is the third line (The one that includes the text "peach"). So I tried this:

```
for fruits in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'half'}):
    if 'font-size: 0.8em;text-align: center;width: 28%;' in str(fruits):
         print(fruits.text)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't print anything at all. I tried some other stuff as well but I couldn't find a working solution.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

ah sorry, I guess I wasn't precise enough. I'm trying to loop through a bunch of somewhat equal source codes and the text "peach" doesn't remain the same all the time. It could be "peach", "strawberry", "banana", "tuna" or any other food somehow. only the class and the style is always the same..

**EDIT2:**

Inspired by alexce's solution, I found my own way to solve the problem:

```
 div = soup.find('div', attrs={'style': 'display: flex'})
 inner_divs = div.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'half'})
 fruits = inner_divs[1].text
```

maybe not the best solution but it's good enough for my little programm :)

BTW: Happy New Year to everybody!

Answer (score 4):

As with the previous answer, I assume you are using `bs4`.

From the question I understand that you need to filter the divs based on attributes: class and style.

The `find_all()` is capable of doing a selection of multiple attributes and the tag type. See [Doc](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments), at the end, the document says that you could pass multiple attributes by passing a dictionary to the `attrs` keyword argument of the `find_all()` function.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<div style="display: flex">
            <div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;width: 33%;"> apple </div>
            <div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;text-align: center;width: 28%;"> peach </div>
            <div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;text-align: right;width: 33%;" title="nofruit"> cucumber </div>
        </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'style': 'font-size: 0.8em;text-align: center;width: 28%;', 'class': 'half'})
for div in divs:
    print(div.text)
```

The output is as desired

```
peach
```

Comment: Thanks man! I tried this already but somehow it didn't print out anything. Maybe I made some stupid mistake as I'm new to coding... But yeah, I found a working solution already.

Comment: The exact code that I posted worked for me, perhaps it is a problem with the source html, which changes somehow. In any case, I'm glad you've found a solution. and Happy New Year!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume you are using [`beautifulsoup4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

---

Also, if the desired `div` is always the second one, you can get it by index:

```
for div in soup.select('div[style$=flex]'):
    inner_divs = div.find_all("div", class_="half")

    print(inner_divs[1].get_text())
```

Or, in one go with `nth-of-type`:

```
for div in soup.select('div[style$=flex] div:nth-of-type(2)'):
    print(div.get_text())
```

FYI, this `select()` call is a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) search.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response! Unfortunately it didn't work somehow. Method 1 & 2 puts up an error "NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.". Method 3 gives another error: "ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "28%"".

Comment: @kikstart okay, sorry, now updated - beautifulsoup did not like the colon in the selector. Hope that helps.